# Unable to run .py file in 13.10

Tags: 13.10, python-2.7

Unable to run .py file in Ubuntu 13.10 server. It returns this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "events_send.py", line 2, in <module> import pika
ImportError: No module named pika
```

Comment: Have you tried installing the `python-pika` package?

Answer (score 1):

your missing the pika package
Before you installing the pika ,install python-pip and git-core, since the pika installation depends on these packages.
Then install pika Packages

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip git-core

sudo pip install pika==0.9.8
```

Comment: did that still not working same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install python-pika package

```
sudo apt-get install python-pika
```

> Pika is a pure-Python implementation of the AMQP 0-9-1 protocol that
>   tries to stay fairly independent of the underlying network support
>   library.

Comment: Did that, nothing, still the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

The message indicates a library is missing. Try installing it with pip using this command:

```
pip install pika
```

You may also have other dependencies that need to be installed as well, we'll know once the application is started after this library is installed.

Comment: Tried this also, nothing, still the same error.

Answer (score -1):

This may be a directory permission problem.
Check:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika-0.9.14.egg-info
```

(depend on which version of python and pika you use)